# Windows symlink to executable - does not open by double click

Tags: windows, symbolic-link, links, double-click

On Windows 7 I created a symbolic link to an executable using:

```
mklink Test.exe C:\Path\to\source.exe
```

But when I try to run it by double clicking on it, i get the "open with" dialog.

Running it from a command window works. The path is right.

Is there any way a symbolic link will be treated like the file it points to (e.g. executable or batch scripts)?

Comment: I see, there are similar symptoms, but no real answer howto actually run a link to an executable by double-clicking in the windows explorer. I would appreciate if no external programs are needed to configure windows to do the job it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a partial solution, in case both the target and the link are on the same disk, you can use a hard link which works fine with double click:

```
mklink /H Test.exe C:\Path\to\source.exe
```

If you have to use symbolic link, I don't know what to do, however, I do know what NOT to do: don't try to associate your link with explorer.exe and the like in that "Open with..." dialog. I have just tried it and spent half an hour fixing my PC afterwards.

Comment: That's the solution. The source of the link targets is on the same disk, so this works for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

#### Windows symlink to executable does not open when double clicking

A recent Windows 7 Update [KB3039066](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46256) broke symbolic links in Windows Explorer and other programs that use the services provided by the Windows shell.

---

#### Fix

> The problem is solved by uninstalling the following update on both the file server and a client computer: [KB3039066](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46256).

After uninstalling it you must restart the PC.

Source: [Symbolic link type changed](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0eefc57f-8c01-450a-a1cf-8e2894a951d9/symbolic-link-type-changed)

---

#### Workarounds

1. Use a hard link (`mklink /h`)
2. System restore to an earlier date.

---

> Same problem here. And yeah, I have installed something: the latest Windows update. I know that's the cause, because I noticed the problem on one computer. Then checked on a different one, and no problem there. I immediately applied Windows update to the second machine, and... bam! Explorer no longer resolves symbolic links.

...

> With a System Restore to a earlier date, I was not able to duplicate this issue, thus I can positively confirm that there currently stands a bug with regards to Symbolic Link behaviour in Windows Explorer, introduced after a recent Windows 7 update.
>
> As a work-around for now: if you would like to navigate to a linked file through Explorer, and you require a programme to access that link, consider using a Hardlink.

Source [Windows 7: Windows Explorer does not follow Symbolic Links](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/364618-windows-explorer-does-not-follow-symbolic-links.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [mklink](http://ss64.com/nt/mklink.html) - Create a symbolic link to a directory or a file, or create a hard file link or directory junction.

Answer (score 1):

[David’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/893273) is not the whole solution for EXE files. Removing
[update KB3039066](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3039066) does fix the thumbnail images for symlinks.

However when you double-click the link in Windows Explorer, the link
cannot be opened, and you receive an error message that resembles the following:

> The specified path does not exist.

This is fixed by installing [update KB3009980](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3009980). Thanks go to
[this forum post](http://sevenforums.com/general-discussion/364618-windows-explorer-does-not-follow-symbolic-links.html#post3304131).

Note you can download the [hotfix here](http://thehotfixshare.net/board/index.php?showtopic=22437) if you do not want to have
Microsoft email it to you.

Ironically, KB3009980 breaks the “Extra Large Icons” and “Large Icons” for
symlinks of JPG files.