# Symlink prompting “Open with”

Tags: windows, windows-registry, symbolic-link, regedit, mklink

I can create a symlink:

```
> mklink bravo.png alfa.png
symbolic link created for bravo.png <<===>> alfa.png
```

> [image: good 240]

However this is on a virtual machine. For some reason if I create one on my
actual computer I am getting this:

> [image: bad 240]

Notice:

1. No thumbnail image
2. If I double click the symlink in the virtual machine, it opens alfa.png in
   Photo Viewer, as expected. However if I double click the symlink on my
   computer it presents the “Open with” window.
3. The symlink says “PNG image” in the virtual machine, it says “SYMLINK File”
   on my computer.

I think some registry setting is the culprit here, but I am not sure which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/893273) on a closed question contains a link to a
[SevenForums thread](http://sevenforums.com/general-discussion/364618-windows-explorer-does-not-follow-symbolic-links.html) on this issue.

One of the users [posted a solution](http://sevenforums.com/general-discussion/364618-windows-explorer-does-not-follow-symbolic-links.html#post3073872) he found on a [Microsoft thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0eefc57f-8c01-450a-a1cf-8e2894a951d9).

Essentially this problem is caused by Windows security [update KB3039066](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/3039066). I
have found that uninstalling it and restarting (not just relogging) fixes the
problem.

Comment: Thanks for the extra information. I will update my answer and close this question as a duplicate.